# How to pass variable name to custom function having h2o function

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to create a function where I need to pass h2o data frame and variable and then use in built H2o function to create partial dependence plots for the model. My function is below:

```
pdp<-function(data,var, bin){
data1 <<- data
var1 <<- var
data1<<-h2o.arrange(data1,var1)
h2o.partialPlot(object = gbm26, data = data1[1:floor(nrow(data1)*0.95),], 
cols = var1 , nbins = 20)
}
pdp(data = dev_final, var = "trans_amt_AVG_0_6m", bin = 20)
```

This function throws an error "Error in checkMatch(by, names(x)) : Column 'var1' in by not found
". is there another way to pass variable name to this function.

Comment: Looks like you are using the python parameter options and not the R options. (see docs http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/h2o_package.pdf). Other checks does var1 exist in your dataframe? what version of h2o are you using?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example as defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve